# "Пришли двое" применительно к женщинам

Tags: грамотная-речь, местоимения, собирательные-числительные

Можно так сказать про двух женщин или *так можно сказать только в том случае, когда не знаешь, кто именно пришёл?* Я имею в виду сказать так, зная кто это, но не уточняя. То есть понятно, что лучше конкретизировать и сказать "Пришли две женщины", но всё же будет ли допустимым вариант сказать именно "Пришли двое", подчёркивая при этом то, насколько прибавилось народу?

Comment: Лучше "пришли две"? О_о

Comment: Не пойму, что вы хотите сказать, Галина.) Знак вопроса... "Пришли две" просто ведь нельзя сказать, только со словом *женщины.*

Comment: Можно сказать просто "пришли две", если до этого уже говорилось о женщинах. Приведу пример: "- А девушки-то на вашей вечеринке были? - Да пришли две..."

Comment: Если уже говорилось, то да. А я рассматриваю случай, когда говоришь это отдельно.

Comment: "Пришли две" просто ведь нельзя сказать, только со словом женщины." - как раз можно, я думаю. "Женщины" будет подразумеваться. Или девочки, девушки, бабушки. Санитарки, роженицы, красавицы - ну все, по кому ясно, что они женского полу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если пол пришедших не столь существенен или заранее неизвестен, то "пришли двое" возможно.

Примерно так:

-- Ко мне на прием есть кто-нибудь?
 -- Да, пришли двое.
 -- Кто именно?
 -- Две женщины, первичные.

А вот если по каким-то причинам в контексте важно подчеркнуть, что они женского полу, то тут уж никак не получится. Примеры есть в других ответах.

Comment: Спасибо! Хороший пример!

Answer (score 3):

Если тот факт, что вновь пришедшие женщины, не существенен и далее никак в тексте не раскрывается, то можно использовать и "пришли двое". С другой стороны, если затем следует нечто вроде "Пришли двое. Одна высокая брюнетка, а вторая кареглазая шатенка...", то тогда безусловно уместнее будет использовать "пришли две женщины".

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!